# How achieve circular layout in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to achieve circular layout in xamarin forms as shown in the attached image. How can i achieve it.

Thanks in advance.[Circular layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIhZs.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a [Relative layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/) or [Absolute Layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/) and to have the Circular Images you can use this plugin - [Circle Image Control Plugin for Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin)

As Alex Turcan pointed out, if you need more image related transformations and effects you can use the [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) plugin.

Comment: Agree. But i personally like ffimageloading plugin, they provide a whole range of transformations together with Circle Transformation, needed by OP

Comment: I have achieved this with custom renderer for the circular layout. Then for arranging the button i used relative layout.

Comment: There is already Plugin available for the same, so you need not actually create a custom render. But yes, you will have more flexibility with your own custom one.